# Why are the contents of the association rule table not visible? only the headings of the columns are visible

Tags: python, apriori

In Python, I tried to generate rules using association rule.

In the output only the column names are displayed and the content is not.
the following are the codes that I have used:

```
frequent_itemsets = apriori(basket_sets, min_support=0.01, use_colnames=True)
rules1 = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="lift", min_threshold=0.0001)
rules1.head()
```

Why is this so?